# import from wordpress migrate with drush

Tags: drush, migrations

UPDATE:

I managed to import my 64MB of content!!!!
I ket expecting to see something new appearing in the confirguration tab from migrate, but that's never been the case.
I also kept having the AJAX error. 
After a while I simply tried the command "drush mi --all -d" and it imported all my content in the background. I didnt get any erros anymore and now all the data has been imported.

Hope this might help some windows users

It me again about Drush..

Drush is not enabling modules and showing me all my enabled modules and all (which wasnt the case yesyerday)

Drush also accepts the  *drush vset migrate_drush_path C\FolderName\Dush\drush.bat*
Youhou!!!

The next thing to do is to see if the PHP directory is in the path of my Drupal:
[image]

It's there so, if I follow the steps from here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1958170
It should be working and I should see further options, which I don't?!

Can someone help me and my wamp server on win 8.1. solve this?